# Android: List View load more with volley

Tags: android, listview

I want when i scroll up to my list view load more data using volley, i created PHP webservice and result

```
{
    "error": false,
    "status_code": 200,
    "total_items": 2,
    "last_page": 1,
    "current_page": 1,
    "per_page": 10,
    "result": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "here title one",
        "city": "city",
        "zone": "zone",
        "type": "type",
        "service": "service",
        "space": "545",
        "date": "2016-08-28 12:24:34",
        "image": "http:\/\/localhost\/my_cms\/public\/assets\/media\/ad-pic.png"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "here title two",
        "city": "city",
        "zone": "zone",
        "type": "type",
        "service": "service",
        "space": "545",
        "date": "2016-08-28 12:24:34",
        "image": "http:\/\/localhost\/my_cms\/public\/assets\/media\/ad-pic.png"
    }]
}
```

My RecentActivity.Java Class

```
public class RecentActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener, AbsListView.OnScrollListener {


    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = HomeActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    // RealstateDataModel json url
    private static final String homeAdsurl = "http://192.168.43.74/my_cms/public/api/realstate/latest?page=";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<RealstateDataModel> realstateData = new ArrayList<RealstateDataModel>();
    private ListView listView;
    private HomeListAdapter homaAdapter;
    int current_page = 0;
    boolean loading;
    RecentActivity activity = null;
    View loadMoreView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recent);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Recent_View);

        String home= getResources().getString(R.string.recient_offers);
        setTitle(home);

        activity = this;
        //List View
        setListAdapter();

        listView.setOnScrollListener(this);


    }

    public void setListAdapter(){
         swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_recent_layout);
        homaAdapter = new HomeListAdapter(this, realstateData);
        listView.setAdapter(homaAdapter);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

        /**
         * Showing Swipe Refresh animation on activity create
         * As animation won't start on onCreate, post runnable is used
         */
        swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

                                        fetchRealStateList();
                                    }
                                }
        );
    }



    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        // showing refresh animation before making http call
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        fetchRealStateList();
    }

    private void fetchRealStateList() {
        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonObjectRequest homeListReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                homeAdsurl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                hidePDialog();
                if (response.length() > 0) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray ResultArray = response.getJSONArray("result");


                        if(realstateData!=null) {
                            realstateData.clear();
                        }

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < ResultArray.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = ResultArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                RealstateDataModel realstateDataBeans = new RealstateDataModel();

                                realstateDataBeans.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                                realstateDataBeans.setCity(obj.getString("city"));
                                realstateDataBeans.setZone(obj.getString("zone"));
                                realstateDataBeans.setType(obj.getString("type"));
                                realstateDataBeans.setService(obj.getString("service"));
                                realstateDataBeans.setSpace(obj.getString("space"));
                                realstateDataBeans.setCreated_at(obj.getString("date"));
                                realstateDataBeans.setImage(obj.getString("image"));
                                // adding movie to movies array
                                realstateData.add(0,realstateDataBeans);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    homaAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                // stopping swipe refresh
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();
                // stopping swipe refresh
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(homeListReq);
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }
}
```

It tried and searched more but when  it try to scroll not effect, i make f 
  onScrollStateChanged and onScroll empty to fill it your helpful code

Answer (score 0):

For example load 10 item at first. When user reach the bottom load 10 more item. How can you understand it is bottom?

```
The last item's bottom == scroll position
```

means end of the list. Load more.

Comment: am new in android and java, Can you describe with actual example ?